# Finite isometric Hilbert space

Tags: hilbert-spaces, isometry

I'm looking for concrete examples of finite dimensional isometric (one-to-one to $\mathbb{R}^p$) Hilbert spaces.
The more the marrier.

Comment: Are you looking only for Hilbert spaces isometric to $\mathbb{R}^p$, or just any isometry of two Hilbert spaces?

Comment: both really, but preferable to Rp